# Why is this HTML not straightforward?

Tags: html

http://codejanitor.us/nightclub2/

Why are my hello's not:

1. expanding the div containing them
2. staying inside the div?

Comment: They do look like they expanded the div containing them and stayed inside the div.  Can you please be more specific?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow instructions

Change your markup to this

```
<div id="header">
    <div style="float: left;">
        hello<br>
        hello<br>
        hello<br>
        hello<br>
    </div>
    <!-- add clear:both-->
    <div style="clear: both;">
    </div>
</div>
```

Change your css:

```
#header {
    background-image: url("images/header.gif");
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    width: 873px; /* remove width */
    padding: 0px 50px; /* add padding to header */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You aren't containing them, see http://work.arounds.org/issue/3/clearing-floats/

Throw overflow hidden on the `#header`, basically. And all you'd need to do after is add left margin because they are rightfully adjusted to the top left.